# Unmarshalling Error [com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException]

Tags: vb.net, proxy-classes, soapheader

I am communicating with a partner's webservice using proxy classes they've provided.

I have this line of code which is throwing an exception:

```
Dim response As requestWebRemittanceResponse = Me.webRemittanceService.requestWebRemittance(webRemittanceRequest)
```

webRemittanceService is and instance of one of these proxy classes and webRemittanceRequest is an instance of another.

Which seems rather straight forward, but the following exception is something I've never seen and does not help much as I cannot step into the requestWebRemittance(webRemittanceRequest) method.

```
    Unmarshalling Error: [com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException] Invalid character reference: null character not allowed in XML content. at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,391]
```

The partner is saying that it's not something from their side.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem which made me feel like an idiot.

I was decrypting a password that needs to be sent to the webservice.

The decrypter used was adding an unprintable character to the password string.